# how to remove/omit file attribute from the dired buffer?

Tags: emacs, dired

In emacs dired buffer, each line will be shown like

```
  drwxrwxrwx     0 Sep 20  2011 afolder
  -rw-rw-rw- 16435 Mar 22 11:04 a.txt
```

How to remove or omit the authority information and make it look like

```
       0 Sep 20  2011 afolder
   16435 Mar 22 11:04 a.txt
```

I use window xp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extension called [dired-details](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredDetails) it probably can do that. Also in [sunrise commander](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander) `C-c <backspace>` hides details - and you can contanct the author - for hiding attributes only.